# JavaFX applications are not Running it on browser, its Throwing error?

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

I have installed JDK7 and JavaFX which comes along with JDK. When I try to run the JavaFX Apps on my browser I get the following popup which shows this error:-

```
Java Plug-in 10.7.2.10
Using JRE version 1.7.0_07-b10 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Documents and Settings\376819
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
    Match: beginTraversal
Match: digest selected JREDesc: JREDesc[version 1.6+, heap=-1--1, args=null, href=http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se, sel=false, null, null], JREInfo: JREInfo for index 0:
    platform is: 1.7
    product is: 1.7.0_07
    location is: http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
    path is: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    args is: null
    native platform is: Windows, x86 [ x86, 32bit ]
    JavaFX runtime is: JavaFX 2.2.0 found at C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\
    enabled is: true
    registered is: true
    system is: true

    Match: ignoring maxHeap: -1
    Match: ignoring InitHeap: -1
    Match: digesting vmargs: null
    Match: digested vmargs: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: JVM args after accumulation: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: digest LaunchDesc: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/Ensemble.jnlp
    Match: digest properties: []
    Match: JVM args: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: endTraversal ..
    Match: JVM args final: 
    Match: Running JREInfo Version    match: 1.7.0.07 == 1.7.0.07
     Match: Running JVM args match: have:<>  satisfy want:<>
```

Please tell me whats gone wrong??

I am using Windows XP and JDK7 with JavaFX

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this oracle thread:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2427666

In that case the main class was not set in the JNLP but it also shows how to output the error messages.